# find last merged git branch in master

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I have main branch in git: `master`

and a number of feature branches: `feature/adding-some-func` and etc.

After the merging `feature` branch to `master` I have commit with message like:

`Merge pull request #33 in test-proj from feature/adding-some-func to master`

How can i get the name of just merged branch(feature/adding-some-func) after the cloning repository? So, as result I need to get feature/adding-some-func but in the logs i see only SHA, Commit Authors

Comment: Try `git log --oneline --merges master`, which lists all the merge commits reachable from `master`. You could add `-1` to list only the last one.

Comment: Are you comfortable relying on the generated commit messages? Has it to be found by a script, or is it ok to look manually (parse the commit message yourself)?

Comment: have to be found by a script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be very specific, you can use:

```
git log --merges origin/master --oneline --grep='^Merge pull request #\([0-9]\+\) in \(.\+\) from \(.\+\) to master' -1
```